# Book on spectroscopy (line dependency on parameters)

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser, spectroscopy, absorption

I am trying to find a book (undergraduate level) on Spectroscopy. I am interested in how molecular absorption lines depend on parameters like temperature and pressure (for example with gases). Can anyone suggest a good book?

PS I searched Phys.SE but didn't find an answer that covers my needs.

Comment: More on [resource-recommendations+spectroscopy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations+spectroscopy).

Comment: If you are looking for actual data, it's far more likely to be contained in experimental papers than in textbooks. Did you do a literature search?

Comment: I claim that temperature and pressure effects to absorption lines is far from undergraduate level material. 

For temperature effects on lineshape modelling in theory (and computation), look for FCclasses code and papers around it. Here is one paper of perhaps of interest also:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2210271X14001182

Comment: @MikaelKuisma I'd disagree, this was textbook material in my physics courses. I may be wrong in translating the terms from Russian, but I believe, temperature-dependent line shapes undergo *non-uniform* broadening which gives a Gaussian line-shape (due to the Doppler effect). It then depends on the natural line-width of the absorption line in question (whether Doppler broadening will be dominant or not).

Comment: And here's a reference http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atomic/broaden.html

Comment: That is one thing. This is for dilute atoms. For molecules with a finite pressure, there is also the environment and the nuclear degrees of freedom. You have to resolve all the vibrational transitions, collisions and environment dielectric effects (for both the nuclear and electronic degrees of freedom), life time is also a very non-trivial quantity to compute. But agreed, it all depends on the level of description. Unfortunately, I don't have any undergraduate level books to recommend about this.